# How do I fill a dataset in an SSRS subreport?

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, reportviewer

This seems like it should be trivial but I'm having difficulties.

I have a main report, I have been filling datasets as follows in `ReportViewer.aspx.cs.`

```
ReportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = "~/SummaryReport.rdlc";
ReportDataSource requestsSource = new ReportDataSource();
requestsSource.Name = "RequestHeadersDataSet";
requestsSource.Value = GetSummaryRequestsDataSet(); // Returns DT
ReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(requestsSource);
```

I also have a subreport, which is referenced in my main report within a row-group in a table. The dataset has column `RequestName`. I pass this in through the Subreport Properties in the Parameters tab.

As soon as I add a dataset to the subreport, I get an error: `Data retrieval failed for the subreport.` Unsurprising, considering I never filled it with anything.

But how can I add to the subreport datasource? The reportpath for ReportViewer is set to my main report.

Both use the same dataset, if this is of any consequence.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [SubreportProcessing Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.winforms.localreport.subreportprocessing.aspx) to set your data source. See following [walkthrough](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlforum/archive/2011/01/03/walkthrough-add-a-subreport-in-local-report-in-reportviewer.aspx) also.

```
ReportViewer.LocalReport.SubreportProcessing +=
                new SubreportProcessingEventHandler(exampleSubreportProcessingEventHandler);

    void exampleSubreportProcessingEventHandler(object sender, SubreportProcessingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("SubReportDataSet", GetSummaryRequestsDataSet()));
    }
```

From provided link [SubreportProcessing Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.winforms.localreport.subreportprocessing.aspx).

> The SubreportProcessing event is triggered for every instance of the
>   subreport in the main report, and not just for each subreport
>   definition. If a report contains multiple subreports instances from
>   the same report definition, this event is triggered for each instance.
>
> If the main report has several subreports, you can examine the
>   ReportPath property of the SubreportProcessingEventArgs class to
>   determine which subreport is being processed and supply data for that
>   subreport.

Comment: Thanks for the response. How does this work when I have multiple subreports, each with their own dataset?