# How to repeat the tablix with cells based on datatable

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, rdlc

I have two tablix in my Report Page. They are, Tablix1 and Tablix2.

These two tablix's refers to one dataset. That dataset is having four different datatables.

**What I want is:**

I want to print the page like the below order,

```
Tablix1 = Datatable1
Tablix2 = Datatable2
Tablix1 = Datatable3
Tablix2 = Datatable4
```

**My code**

For loop will be come here. In this case, two times the loop will continue. So , the below code will execute twice.

```
Dim dsMposet As DataSet = New DataSet
Dim dtTable As DataTable = New DataTable
dtTable = test1 // datatable will change based on "for loop"
dtTable.TableName = "Style"
dsMposet.Tables.Add(dtTable)
Dim dtTable1 As DataTable = New DataTable
dtTable1 = test2 //datatable will change based on "for loop"
dtTable1.TableName = "Peace"
dsMposet.Tables.Add(dtTable1)
frm = New frmPrintPage(dsMposet) //Print things will happen here
frm.ShowDialog() // Here is the place where the print will occur
```

So,

**Is this possible ?**. If so, where i need to alter the code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

To achieve that layout, I would use your current report as a subreport.  The new parent report wrapped around that could just have 2 subreport objects, both referencing your existing report.

If you need more dynamic repetition then you could create a dataset (with as many rows as you need iterations), and a tablix with just a single cell with the subreport.

To achieve the manipulation of the subreport's datasets you are after, you probably then need to add an event handler for the SubreportProcessing event, e.g.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28331298/1787137

Comment: I'll be finishing work in a few hours and then on holidays until this bounty expires. I hope I have given you enough information to resolve your challenge?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. And thanks for your reply. Before, I proceed i would like to inform you that I'm very much beginner to this ssrs. And now I'm able to understand the concept of subreport(with the help of this link - http://www.sqlcircuit.com/2012/11/ssrs-how-to-create-subreport.html). But I'm not able to understand your answer. On that link, on click of city, they are opening subreport. Here where you want me to open the subreport ? What main report will be having ?'

Comment: That blog post is a bit confusing. I would ignore all of the "Section 4.     Steps to create Sub Report in the form of Drill through" - this does not describe a Sub Report in SSRS terms, but rather a Drill through report. A true Sub Report is shown in "Section 5".

Comment: Here's an example of the steps to embed a Sub Report object in a tablix, to get dynamic repetition: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24744728/1787137

Comment: In my case, there is no click or select event. Simply I want to display the tablix 1 and tablix 2. But repetition is needed.

Comment: Hello. I resolved the mentioned issue. Thanks for your help. I got other one. Hope you can help me. I have one tablix with two rows. One row is containing one tablix and the other one is having another table. Here the issue is, I have one expr in page header, the value of this expr is retrieving from the second tablix (i.e.second row from the  main tablix). So, when first tablix is displaying(i.e. first row from the main tablix), I'm getting #error on that textbox. I can guess that the value is not there in first tablix so error occurred. How to give a relation to first row from second row?